# Is using unique usernames as _ids in mongodb instead of ObjectId a good practice?

Tags: mongodb, objectid

Is it a bad practice in MongoDb to use username string as a unique _id for user collection?

So there won't be surrogate id for each user (we all have this habit in relation databases)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of allowing such a thing in mongodb, you are good to go **as long as** you can ensure uniqueness.

In terms of it being a better practice that is a different story. It depends on the access pattern. How you plan to access the database and how your application will interact with it. If that is what your application needs go ahead. However keep in mind that if you replace the object ID, you will lose some of the ups that come with it, like the timestamp embedded ...etc.